# Problem executing 'import mysql.connector' w/ python (MAC OS Mojave 10.14.6)

Tags: python, mysql, database, path, homebrew

So..
I am trying to connect an existing piece of python code to MySQL DB. Have the connector/driver for MAC.
I am currently in REPL playing w/ it.

I run the command 'import mysql.connector'
The response I get is:
**File"Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions/3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector. **init**.py", line 41, in 
import dns.resolver
moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'**

So I google it and lo and behold, I install dnspython module manually. First using pip, which installs dnspython-1.16.0 w/ a deprecation note about how python2.7 has reached its EOL(End Of Life).
I uninstall it when I see on PyPI that there's a new version: dnspython=2.0.0

Upon uninstallation I see:
**Would Remove:
/users/{username_personal}/Library/python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/dns*
and another file ...../site-packages/dnspython-1.16.9.dis-info/* (..... signifies that the path preceding is same as mentioned right above for the first file)**

*What I think*: Maybe the module is being installed into python 2.7 whereas when i run my import mysql.connector command, it's looking for it at python3.7/..../.. and the installation of dns is being done at python 2.7(which comes pre installed in mac).
So i use pip3 to install the new version of dnspython so it would install it in the python3.7/...

Now, upon more research, I download pyenv using brew to see if I can manage the versions myself and come to a solution. While reading more about it, I thought maybe there's a problem with my $PATH environment variable. I read a bit more about it eventually getting overwhelmed with copious amounts of data online, most of which i can't understand being new at this.

The only way I thought it could work was to ask all the good people here.

Please help me with what the problem is and how i can solve it.

Thanks a ton for reading this long post/question.

Comment: I have been constantly playing with $PATH on my mac for the last 2 hours or so, but can't seem to get rid of the error(no module named 'dns').

Comment: If you think of downvoting the question, I would really appreciate it if you could point out what I could do better. I wouldn't mind learning how to ask questions here. Thanks

Comment: Did you try pip3 install instead of pip?

Comment: I did just now, Commented the whole thing below.. @Rohit    Please take a look and help :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens to `import mysql.connector` after you using `pip3` to install `dnspython`? Can you share the traceback message?

If there's something wrong with modules, rather than using `pyenv` to switch Python version, can you try to [use `venv` to create](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-virtual-environment) so you could sort of "start fresh" in terms of modules installed for your project and see what happens when you `import mysql.connector` again?

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install mysql-connector-python # installing a fresh copy of mysql connector to `venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`
```

Comment: -- pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages --

So....I apparently copied onto the clipboard, the command to installing dnspython from PyPI and it was using pip instead of pip3 to install the module. Realizing, I tried the command and got a warning

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
So I google it and eventually got led to brew update and brew upgrade. The first 3 lines of the comment are what i get from that.

Comment: The location of that site-package directory is different from the location I get from this Traceback when I use 'import mysql.connector' in REPL.          It's looking in the wrong place.
    ** Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
      import dns.resolver  
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns' **

@yibo

Comment: When I start the REPL by issuing ''pyhton3'' command in the terminal, it gives me         Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3........... Different versions of python3 are installed.

Comment: @StatusMindless Did you solve the issue by yourself in the end? Using `python3 -m pip install ` should ensure the installation is at the right place.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I acually bypassed the whole issue by installing a VM on my computer. Installing only one version of python there and then working from there. It was like a couple hours work to get an idea about everything. 
My files in the Mac are so messed up, someone suggested I ditch the idea of concentrating on the wrong stuff and keep my focus on the things I am interested in. This was just an issue that popped up and had nothing to do with my actual problem. I took the advice and bypassed the whole ordeal.@yibo